# Why does crypt() return int instead of char? WSL

Tags: linux, wsl-2

According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html the function returns char. I use WSL and when looking at the documentation in WSL it has different parameters. [image]

[image]

But in my code it says it returns an int. I'm using WSL on windows 10.

Comment: Please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) and edit your question to include the text (code-block, Mardown) formatted input and output.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably analyzer in your IDE can't find header with `crypt()` declaration. It is showing empty parameters list as well. If not specified, return type of function defaults to `int`.